# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when trying to use GemBox.Pdf PdfDocument.Load

Tags: c#, gembox-pdf

Using Gembox.Pdf 17.01386 free-license.
I’m receiving a PDF file in base64 format, then I convert the string using Convert.FromBase64String to turn into a byte array.
Then I turn it into a new MemoryStream, and the I try to call PdfDocument.Load(memoryStream). When i call the Load method, my application brings the following exception:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: ‘Argument must be between 1 and 2 (inclusive). Arg_ParamName_Name
ArgumentOutOfRange_ActualValue’

I already tried to set the memoryStream position to 0, with no success.
The error occurs only with some pdf files. With other, there is no error. I really don’t know what else to do.

This is my code, changed for brevity:

```
public string GetSignature(string authorizationToken, string PdfBase64, UserModel userModel)
{
GemBox.Pdf.ComponentInfo.SetLicense(“FREE-LIMITED-KEY”);
GemBox.Document.ComponentInfo.SetLicense(“FREE-LIMITED-KEY”);
byte bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(PdfBase64);

var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
PdfDocument document2 = PdfDocument.Load(memoryStream);
}
```

I’d really appreciate any help. Thanks